# Json format output

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing

I am new to development, and learning angular 2 and node. Now working on a project with API integration and in the code below. I am sending all JSON data to array, I tried using JSON.stringify but did not get the desired output. And I need this kind of output:

```
 Area = [
    { value: '3', label: 'sports' },
    { value: '4', label: 'fest' },
    { value: '5', label: 'music' }
    ];
```

My ts code is like this

```
    var Area = [];
    area=> {
           console.log(departments);
           area.map(function(areas) {
             var array = {"value":area._id,"label":area.areaFor};
             Area.push(array);
           })
           console.log(Area);
         },
         error => {
           console.log(error);
         });
    but i am getting this output in console
    label
    "sports"
    value
    2
    label
    "fest"
    value
    3
    label
    "music"
    value
    5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, I changed area to areas inside map function.

```
area = [
            { value: '3', label: 'sports' },
            { value: '4', label: 'fest' },
            { value: '5', label: 'music' }
        ];
        constructor() {
            var Area = [];

               Area = this.area.map(function(areas) {
                return {"value":areas.value,"label":areas.label};

               })
               console.log(Area);

        }
```

Comment: @schedular, could you please accept my answer if it helped you.